# How to hide view in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I want to hide View in items of RecyclerView .
I have `if/else` statement in BindViewHolder as shown:

```
if (position == list.size() - 1)
{
   holder.divider.setVisibility(View.Gone)
}
```

It was working initially and my View got disappeared but when I scroll back, some View also got disappeared, and I have no idea to solve this , i tried `holder.getAdapterposition` but still happening the same . It will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: you need to set visibility values inside your model class

Comment: Add visibility gone for the view you want to hide and set the visibility(View.Visible) for remaining views.

Comment: tks @Divyesh , i will try both of you and savin

Comment: Did the solution worked? @little_Friend

Comment: @SavinSharma your solution worked very well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you want to use `if` statement inside `onBindViewHolder`, **always put else with it**. RecyclerView reuse views, so it should know if anything special regarding specific rows as well as normal formatting for normal rows.

```
if (position == list.size() - 1){
   holder.divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
   holder.divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```